# Путаница в IPv6 локальных адресах

Tags: c#, .net, windows, сеть, ipv6

Есть один сетевой адаптер, мне нужно узнать его локальный IPv6, для отправки запросов с сокета (сокет в режиме `DualMode`) через этот IP.

Проблема вот в чем. При получении списка локальных IP через `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList` выдается два! адреса IPv6. Один адрес как раз из свойств сетевой карты, а второй адрес из виртуального `Microsoft 6 to 4 tunnel adapter`.

Какой же адрес использовать для сокета, и для чего вообще этот адаптер нужен?

**Update:**

Попробовал направить запросы сокета через оба IPv6 локальных адреса. В итоге тот, который указан в настройках сетевого адаптера - нерабочий, а тот, который выдан `Microsoft 6 to 4 tunnel adapter` - рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Для проверки IPv6 (и заодно IPv4) пришлось писать такой метод:

```
private static bool CheckLocalIPv4_v6(string ip)
        {
            using (var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Unspecified))
            {
                try
                {
                    var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 0);
                    var isIPv6 = (endPoint.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6) ? true : false;
                    if (isIPv6)
                        socket.DualMode = true;
                    socket.Bind(endPoint);
                    socket.Connect((isIPv6) ? "2001:4860:4860::8888" : "8.8.8.8", 53);
                    return socket.Connected;
                }
                catch { return false; }
            }
        }
```

p.s. работает только на .NET 4.5 и выше, [пруф.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/01/08/dual-mode-sockets-never-create-an-ipv4-socket-again/)

p.p.s. варианта лучше я не нашел, если есть что-то более хорошее - поделитесь =)